# Xamarin.Forms Android Scrollview eats PinchZoomGesture

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm making app with using XF pcl. 
If I add Pinchzoomgesture on View inside Scrollview, It's working fine on iOS but not on Android.

Seems like a bug?

Any a workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug. One workaround may be to use the third party plugin [Mr.Gestures](http://www.mrgestures.com/#Events) which supports `Pinch` gestures in a `ScrollView`.

Either that or you could file a bug report at: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Or you could have a go at fixing this issue yourself: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Thanks. I should check more.

Comment: I think the exact file you need would probably be this one: [https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/9dff4c16508452512c5faa36788f65ba6419170e/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/ScrollViewRenderer.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/9dff4c16508452512c5faa36788f65ba6419170e/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/ScrollViewRenderer.cs)

Comment: Thanks. I filed a bug at bugzilla. https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51582

Comment: Real problem occurs when I add a pinchgesture on View in ScrollView INSIDE scrollview.

Comment: `scrollview` inside `scrollview` sounds like trouble. you may want to readdress what you are trying to achieve

Comment: You can imagine carouselView(horizontal ScrollView) which has vertical scrollView each. And I faced trouble to use PinchGesture.